# Changing URL string variable for only one link

Tags: javascript

We add link tracking in our outbound links in the URL strings, which is based on a global variable that's declared on the page, but need the ability to modify only one of the links to read a different value. For example, in the sample below, all links for Ask, Bing, Duck Duck Go, and Yahoo, should be appended with the value "webcampaign", such as this:

```
http://www.ask.com/?group=&placement=webcampaign
http://www.bing.com/?group=&placement=webcampaign
http://www.duckduckgo.com/?group=&placement=webcampaign
http://www.yahoo.com/?group=&placement=webcampaign
```

However, we need Google to read like this:

```
http://www.google.com/?group=&placement=defLink
```

Here's the challenge. How can I modify the JavaScript so that the Google link reads differently than the rest of the links?

Here's a simple example where all links would have the same URL string appendage:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Link Test</title>
<script>
var placement = "webcampaign";
</script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="globalscripts_plain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="http://www.ask.com">Ask</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com">Duck Duck Go</a>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com" id="defLink">Google</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the script that appends each link with the placement variable, which is declared at the top of the markup:

```
(function($, undefined) {
var App = (window.App || (window.App = {}));
$.extend(App,{
    getParameterByName : function (name) {},
});
$(function() {
    $('a[href^="http"]').each(function() {
        var $a = $(this),
            q = $a.attr('href') ? $a.attr('href').indexOf('?') : -1,
            contents = $a.html();
        if (q == -1) {
            $a.attr('href', $a.attr('href') + '?group=' + '&placement=' + placement);
        } else {
            $a.attr('href', $a.attr('href') + '&group=' + '&placement=' + placement);
        }
    });
});
})(window.jQuery);
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/v92L8pbw/1/

Comment: Why on Earth would you do all that jQuery to make the links different anyways. Just change them in the HTML. If you must use jQuery just use a `RegExp` on the `.attr('href')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can simplify this a bit and use anchor tag properties like [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search) to see if query params already exist and use `attr(function)` which exposes the existing href value

```
var placement = "webcampaign";    

$('a[href^="http"]').attr('href', function(_, oldHref) {
  var placementVal = oldHref.indexOf('google.com') > -1 ? 'defLink' : placement;
  var  newQuery = this.search ? '&' : '?';
  newQuery += 'group=&placement=' + placementVal;
  return oldHref + newQuery;
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qzxsx1xr/2/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Since this code is inherited, and seems to be a one off fix:

Notice that the google `<a>` tag has an id attribute of "defLink". You can use that to target elements in the `.each` method call.

Check when the ID of an `<a>` tag is equal to `"defLink"` an **if statement** or in a **ternary expression**, then you can change the value that is appended as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href^="http"]').each(function() {
    var $a = $(this),
        q = $a.attr('href') ? $a.attr('href').indexOf('?') : -1,
        contents = $a.html(),
   // the next line overwrites the global value 
   // of placement if ID is defLink
        placement = ($a.attr('id') === "defLink") ? "defLink":placement;
    if (q == -1) {
      $a.attr('href', $a.attr('href') + '?group=' + '&placement=' + placement);
    } else {
      $a.attr('href', $a.attr('href') + '&group=' + '&placement=' + placement);
    }
  });
});
```